# How does JavaScript garbage collection work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, garbage-collection

Garbage collection is a behind-the-scenes language feature, so I'm assuming it's going to be slightly different in each browser and this question is specifically about Google Chrome.

How does Chrome's garbage collector work- what triggers it, can/should I manually trigger it, and (possibly out of scope for a single question) what patterns might cause memory leaks to get past it?

Comment: As chrome usew the V8 javascript engine, you could have a look at this article, which describes this topic in detail: http://jayconrod.com/posts/55/a-tour-of-v8-garbage-collection. I think that this topic is too big to answer here (but maybe in a simplified way?).

Comment: "so I'm assuming it's going to be slightly different in each browser and this question is specifically about Google Chrome." - not to the extent that it should be observable from JS code (modulo bugs and timing differences)